# Expedia hotel reservation status - Booked vs. Confirmed?

Tags: hotels, expedia

I've booked the same hotel for two non-contiguous nights on Expedia. The reservation status of one of them is Booked and the other one is Confirmed.

My question is...  what's the difference?

I note that the one that is booked has had a charge applied to my credit card whereas the one that is confirmed has not. Does this mean that the one that's been confirmed will be charged to my credit card when I check in? If so would it be possible to change it so that it'd be charged to my credit card now vs later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at [Expedia](https://www.expedia.com/service/?langid=1033#/article/12824) the word 'booked' refers to what you, the customer does, makes a request, and 'confirmed' to what the provider does, acknowledging your request and agreeing to honor it. Of course, for absolute certainty, visit the site's [Customer Service](https://www.expedia.com/service/) portal and hit the **Contact Us** radio button to email, or call 1-866-310-5768 (local, toll-free) or +1 404-728-8787 (from abroad, charges apply).